# render latex as svg in JavaScript and display the result with paper.js

Tags: javascript, svg, mathjax, paperjs

The following code gives "script error". Any help greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.11/paper-full.min.js"></script>

<script>
  window.MathJax = {
    // options
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas_1"></canvas>
```

javascript

```
var graphScope = new paper.PaperScope();
var canvas_1 = document.getElementById('canvas_1');
graphScope.setup(canvas_1);
graphScope.activate();

const latexToImg = function(formula) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let wrapper = MathJax.tex2svg(`${formula}`, {
      em: 10,
      ex: 5,
      display: true
    })
    let output = {
      svg: "",
      img: ""
    }
    let mjOut = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
    // mjOut.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    output.svg = mjOut.outerHTML
    var image = new Image()
    image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(output.svg)));
    image.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      output.img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      resolve(output.img)
    }
    image.onerror = function() {
      reject()
    }
  })
}

const svgGroup = graphScope.project.importSVG(latexToImg('x^2'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MathJax and Paper.js both work with SVG directly, so there's no apparent need to create an intermediate canvas element. Furthermore, `MathJax.tex2svg` creates an SVG DOM element, which Paper.js can use ([`importSVG`](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#importsvg-svg) can work with an SVG string, a DOM element, or a url string). This simplifies the code considerably, since it removes all of the canvas operations and all of the operations are synchronous.

For some reason though, the size is pretty tiny, so I've scaled it up 20 times.

```js
var graphScope = new paper.PaperScope();
var canvas_1 = document.getElementById('canvas_1');
graphScope.setup(canvas_1);
graphScope.activate();
const latexToImg = function(formula) {
  let wrapper = MathJax.tex2svg(formula, {
    em: 10,
    ex: 5,
    display: true
  })
  return wrapper.querySelector('svg');
}
const svgGroup = graphScope.project.importSVG(latexToImg('x^2'));
var bounds;
svgGroup.scale(20);
// for automatic scaling, use these lines instead:
// bounds = svgGroup.strokeBounds;
// svgGroup.scale(40 / bounds.height);
bounds = svgGroup.strokeBounds;
svgGroup.position.x = -bounds.x;
svgGroup.position.y = -bounds.y;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.11/paper-full.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.MathJax = {
    // options
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas_1"></canvas>
```

Comment: This works perfectly - many thanks! Is there a similar method to render an equation stored as asciimath rather than latex?

Comment: I don't have much familiarity with MathJax, and while it seems like it should be possible, I couldn't figure it out from the documentation. I did find [`ASCIIMathTeXImg.js`](https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml/blob/master/asciimath-based/ASCIIMathTeXImg.js) which can convert AsciiMath to LaTeX via the global `AMTparseAMtoTeX` function. A quick test combining it with my answer seems to work. If you run into difficulty feel free to open another question and point it my way.

Comment: Many thanks again Steve. I got some help with this from the MathJax users' forum:
https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users/c/higZb3L7KvU

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look at your code, I would say that:

1. you are passing a promise to the `importSVG` function
2. the `importSVG` function expects to receive a SVG string and your promise will resolve with a PNG image data url

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to change this, but I can't manage it - e.g.canvas.toDataURL('image/svg') does not work. Do you have any suggestions of how to fix this?